# How to read data (columns and rows) from google spreadsheet and log in

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a login screen in google script and i am using a spreadsheet for a database to read data. I dont have clue how to read data and proceed to a different page.

Here is the code for the login without the function to read and move to the next page:

```js
function doGet(){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var panel1 = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var panel2 = app.createVerticalPanel().setId("panel2");
  var grid = app.createGrid(12, 2).setId('Etine');
  var table = app.createFlexTable().setId('table').setTag('0');

  var gebruikerlabel = app.createLabel("Gebruikersnaam");
  var gebruikerfield = app.createTextBox().setName("gebruikerfield");
  var wachtwoordlabel = app.createLabel("Wachtwoord");
  var wachtwoordfield = app.createPasswordTextBox().setName("wachtwoordfield");

  var button = app.createButton("Login").setStyleAttribute("background",        "#2E64FE").setId("button");
  var infoLabel = app.createLabel('probeer opnieuw')
    .setVisible(false).setId('info');

  panel2.add(image);
  panel2.add(gebruikerlabel);
  panel2.add(gebruikerfield);
  panel2.add(wachtwoordlabel);
  panel2.add(wachtwoordfield);
  panel2.add(button);    
  //...
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Your posted code is unrelated to the question. See SpreadsheetApp.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a click handler to your button, add the panel as a callback element for this handler. Then access the spreadsheet on the callback function. Something like this:

```js
  //...
  button.addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler('login').addCallbackElement(panel2));
  //...
  return app;
} //close doGet()

//example of login function
function login(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var gebruiker = e.parameter['gebruikerfield'].toLowerCase();
  var wachtwoord = e.parameter['wachtwoordfield'];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('<your-spreadsheet-id>');
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('<users-sheet>');
  var data = s.getDataRange().getValues();
  var gebruikerCol = 0; //usernames on column A
  var wachtwoordCol = 1; //passwords on column B
  for( var i = 1; i < data.length; ++i ) { //i=1 to skip header
    if( data[i][gebruikerCol] === gebruiker ) {
      if( data[i][wachtwoordCol] === wachtwoord ) {
        startApp(app);
      } else {
        app.getElementById('info').setVisible(true);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return app;
}

function startApp(app) {
  // remove/hide login panel, add new one
}
```